# AWS auto-scaling desired capacity changed automatically and is not coming down

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs, aws-auto-scaling

I have an auto-scaling group with two target scaling policies, one is based on SQS backlog and another on CPU-Utilization. I have initially set the capacities at minimum-1,desired-1,maximum-4. During the scale-out process, my desired capacity changed to 2 automatically. Now all the messages in the queues were successfully processed and the two scaling processes are requesting the ASG to scale in. But, the desired capacity is still at 2 and is not coming down. Is there a logic that I am missing? or do I need to do it manually?
[image]

Comment: Can you please show us your Scale-In Policies?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein hi I have uploaded the image with two target tracking policies. One is base on a custom metric and another is based on CPU utilization.

Comment: You seem to have two Target Tracking policies -- one related to Average CPU of EC2 instance(s), and the other related to what appears to be a custom metric? It isn't clear what would happen if the two policies conflict with each other. I would recommend choosing only one Target Tracking metric.

Comment: As per AWS documentation, a conflict would not occur between two target scaling policies as AWS tries to provide the maximum number of instances after comparing the two policies. Now the scale-in alarms for both the policies are active and still, the desired capacity is not coming down to its original set value.

Comment: Well, perhaps one policy is wanting 2 instances and the other policy is wanting 1 instance. From what you say, it would provide "the maximum number of instances", which would be 2.

Comment: Well, the case is, now both the policies are requesting for scale-in of ASG. But, when the scale-out happened the desired capacity changed to 2 from 1 and now is not changing back.

Comment: Can you show us the Scaling History that is saying that both policies want a Desired Capacity of 1?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Hi, The problem finally got solved. It was a problem due to elastic beanstalk upgrade failure. Once I sorted that issue, the desired capacity automatically came down.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found that scaling policies are involved. For example, if we set a scaling policy based on CPU utilization, like scaling up when it goes above 30%, AWS automatically adjusts the desired capacity, but only up to the maximum limit we specify. When CPU utilization decreases, the desired capacity can reach the minimum capacity value.

In essence, the desired capacity serves as a pointer that can change within the specified minimum and maximum values. However, this change only happens when scaling policies are defined. If no scaling policies are set, the desired capacity stays the same by default, so manual adjustments are necessary if we want it to change.

For more reference you can go to this: [What "desired instances" is needed for? AWS Amazon Webservices AutoScaling group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882408/what-desired-instances-is-needed-for-aws-amazon-webservices-autoscaling-group)